# How to show a messagebox in vb.net to know data are successfully inserted?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

The code below is simply an insertion code that calls a stored procedure **InsertDataIntoTable** that i created in sql. The code works but what I want to add is a messagebox (or a label) to ensure that data has been successfully inserted.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
    Try

        sqlCon = New SqlConnection(strConn)

        Using (sqlCon)

            Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand()

            sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon

            sqlComm.CommandText = "InsertDataIntoTable"
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Years", ddl_year.SelectedItem.Text)
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("StateForest", SFtx.Text)
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("PrivateForest", PFtx.Text)
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("TotalForest", totalForesttx.Text)
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("PercentageSF", PercentageSFtx.Text)
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("PercentageTotal", PercentageTotal.Text)

            sqlCon.Open()

            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
        LoadData()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: Are you using winforms or webforms?

Comment: Don't forget to implement the exception handler; silently eating errors isn't usually a good thing.

Comment: I'm using webforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your `sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()`:

`Dim RowsAffected as Integer = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()`

`.ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected so you can compare the value to ensure that a data has been successfully inserted.

Something like:

```
If RowsAffected > 0 Then
     Msgbox("Record has been successfully inserted")
End If
```