# how to display value in msg from database in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

How to show value in message box from database in vb.net? I need help

I want to show value if I put wrong value in textbox then message box show the original value from the database.

```
        Dim cmdAB As String
        Dim daAB As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dsAB As DataSet
        Dim dtAB As DataTable

        cmdAB = "SELECT * FROM English_Test WHERE school_code= '" & school_code & "' and child_id= '" & child_id & "' and english_1= '" & English_1TextBox.Text & "'"
        daAB = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdAB, cnn)
        dtAB = New DataTable()

        dsAB = New DataSet()

        daAB.Fill(dsAB, "English_Test")

        dtAB = dsAB.Tables("English_Test")

        If (dtAB.Rows.Count > 0) Then

            English_2TextBox.Focus()

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("English 1: " & dtAB.Rows(0).Item("english_1") & " not found.", "" & Name & " - Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

            English_1TextBox.Enabled = True
            English_1TextBox.Text = Nothing
            English_1TextBox.Focus()

        End If
```

Comment: First: use parameters to avoid SQL injection. Second: for me it is unclear what you want to do. Third: we may help you if you got problems, but we won't solve your homework for you.

Comment: Simply, how to get value in messagebox from database in vb.net?

Comment: Surprisingly, this is the only similar post in Stack Overflow: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737036/how-to-show-a-messagebox-in-vb-net-to-know-data-are-successfully-inserted), so I would not consider it a duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you use parameters, also the Using...EndUsing blocks ensure that your objects are closed and disposed properly even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub CheckOriginalData()
        Dim Name As String = ""
        Dim school_code As String = ""
        Dim child_id As String = ""
        Dim dtAB As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Dim cmdAB As String = "SELECT * FROM English_Test WHERE school_code= @SchoolCode and child_id= @ChildID and english_1= @English1;"
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdAB, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SchoolCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = school_code
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ChildID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = child_id
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@English1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = English_1TextBox.Text
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dtAB.Load(dr)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        If (dtAB.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            English_2TextBox.Focus()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("English 1: " & English_1TextBox.Text & " not found.", Name & " - Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            English_1TextBox.Enabled = True
            English_1TextBox.Text = Nothing
            English_1TextBox.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Lastly, your problem. If your datatable has no rows then referencing a row and a column to get a value is not going to work out. You provided that value and it is still in your textbox not in the database. Remember, it wasn't found.